# How to define or get the value of variable from an api route in express js

Tags: node.js, rest, express, routes

The below is my route api, in that i need to use the var query to an app.get route. How to define globally or pass to another route.

```
app.post('/', function  query_out (req, res) {
  var query = 'SELECT * FROM Unit_Models WHERE Series_ID = ' + req.body.id + ';' 

});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    async.parallel([
        (callback) => db.all('SELECT * FROM Unit_Series;', callback),
        (callback) => db.all('SELECT * FROM Unit_Models', callback),
        (callback) => db.all('SELECT * FROM Unit_Models WHERE Series_ID = ' + req.body.id + ';' , callback),
    ], (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            res.json({
                // Unit_Series: results[0],
                // Unit_Models: results[1],
                results
            });
            // console.log(req.query.d);

            // console.log(results[0]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to take a global approach, make a function with the query you need to call it repeatedly, in the same file or in a separate file and then call it where ever you need it.